# The module has not been deployed. Build failed in Netbeans

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am developing a web application for login form using Servlets in netbeans and MYSQL database.
But when I run the project I am getting error 'The module has not been deployed, Build failed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to undeploy a currently deployed version which is preventing Netbeans to clean preceding the build.

I usually tend to kill Glassfish altogether though.

Answer (score 0):

These can be reasons why you are not able to `Deploy` the project.

Sometimes, existing deployed project or not properly deployed project does not allow to 
deploy the project again.

Right Click on your project from Projects.

Choose **Clean and Build** which will undeploy application at context path if any.

Then again Right Click on your Project and **Deploy**. This should deploy your project.

You should get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)` under `Output` window in your project name tab.

Comment: @aparnaramnath: Can you more elaborate more ? "still it is not working" is bad from a programmer's perspective